# Call to undefined method using multitenancy for laravel

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant

I have a project where I need to implement multitenancy with multi-databases.

I have gone through the installation process, and created a domain for my tenant, but everytime I try to access it I get this error:

`Call to undefined method Stancl\Tenancy\Database\Models\Tenant::domains()`

The domains function is found on a trait called HasDomains, but I cannot figure it out why Laravel cannot resolve it.

Here's my model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Stancl\Tenancy\Contracts\TenantWithDatabase;
use Stancl\Tenancy\Database\Concerns\HasDatabase;
use Stancl\Tenancy\Database\Concerns\HasDomains;
use Stancl\Tenancy\Database\Models\Tenant as ModelsTenant;

class Tenant extends ModelsTenant implements TenantWithDatabase
{
    use HasFactory;
    use HasDatabase;
    use HasDomains;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please share more details. The given error is thrown on accessing a method in another class

Comment: Hi @denis

Were you able to solve this? What's the solution, please?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a tenant?

```
>> $tenant1 = Tenant::create(['id' => 'foo']);
>> $tenant1->domains()->create(['domain' => 'foo.saas.test']);
```

Because as error shows, it calls `HasDomain` and the domain is not present in the DB.

It should fixed if you do it. and take note, change `foo.saas.test` with the domain where the project/tenant URL is hosted.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should adding a row to the database resolve the given error?